# Is it possible to change item's width in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, kotlin, dimensions, android-viewpager2

*ViewPager1* adapter has `public float getPageWidth(final int position)` method that can be used in order to change item's width. But I can't find any information on how to do this with ViewPager2.

Is there a way to change the width of an item in *ViewPager2*?